# Changing record in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that I will be changing its resords regularly every set amount of time ( the time gap between changing the record might change depending, so it might be every 24 hours or every 15 minuets or every 5 sec)

Will this affect the resources I get when signing up for a host ( the desk space and bandwidth)?

And will the website go down during the time I'm updating my records in ?

PS the record I will be changing will also vary in amount and size depending on other things, so if we say that my database is now about 3 megabites, I will be changing a record from this database which might be equal to 2 megabites.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

While disk-space requirements may remain more or less constant, based on your description of what you intend to do, bandwidth is consumed by every SQL command you issue to the host and by every response that you request.  It can add-up rapidly, and surreptitiously.

Incidentally, I strongly suggest that you shop for a host which does not "meter" bandwidth, as in "charging by the x-byte."  You should know what your monthly bill is going to be, with no *(heh, heh ...)* "$urprises."